# Delete array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, each

I'm having a little trouble with the JS `delete()` function.

Straight from Chrome Inspector:

```
> x = [{name: 'hello'}, {name: 'world'}]
> [Object, Object]
> delete x[0]
> true
> $.each (x, function (i, o) {console.log(o.name);})
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> x
> [undefined × 1, Object]
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening? It's causing me issues with that `each`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delete() method on the Array data structure is a little misleading.  When you do the following:

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
delete a[0];
```

delete() does something similar to assigning the array element to undefined. Note that after using delete(), the array is not shifted and the length remains the same:

```
a.length -> 3
a[0] -> undefined
```

So in essence, delete() creates a sparse array and does not alter the length property nor remove the element.  To completely remove the element, you want to do the following:

```
a.splice(0,1)
```

This will both remove the element and alter the array's length property.  So now:

```
a.length -> 2
```

See the the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method for details on method arguments.

Comment: I'll look into splice.
I preferred `delete()` because I'm deleting items in an `each()`.

Comment: What is the intent behind deleting elements while iterating over the array?

Comment: I have a list of elements in Limbo (initially empty, and then add to it). The elements have a `quantity` field
Now I update that list, by adding more elements.
For every existent element in Limbo, I update the quantity, and for elements that don't exist, I add them with `quantity` = 1.
I iterate the elements I want to add, and if I find it in Limbo, I increase the `quantity` and delete the item.
When iterating is done, all I have is elements that need to be added, so I once iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `x[0]` is not the same as slicing that entry out of the array. Element 1 is still at `x[1]` in other words, so `x[0]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

To properly remove objects from the array, you should use the [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
x = [{name: 'hello'}, {name: 'world'}];
x.splice(0,1);
```